Why doesn't the validation loss of my CNN for image classification decrease significantly?
I am creating a CNN network for image classification, but during training, my validation loss does not decrease below 1.2. What is wrong with my network? What should I add or remove from my network?
architecture of my CNN:
class SimpleCNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        super(SimpleCNN, self).__init__()
        # Single convolutional layer
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        

        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        
        # Single fully connected (dense) layer
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2*2*512,512)  # Assuming input images are 64x64 pixels
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv4(x))
        x = self.pool(x)
        
        x = torch.flatten(x,1)  # Flatten the output for the dense layer
        x = self.fc1(x)  # Final dense layer to produce class scores
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        
        return x

I have tried different architectures, but nothing seems to work for me.

Please state what have you tried so far, as you mentioned

Your model might be too small. Try fine-tune a resnet34 model for comparison

What's your training loss? 1.2 is an absolute value which doesn't mean anything without knowing the metric and the data.
